# Add Bootstrap Glyphicon to Right Side of Form Input via Coffeescript using Simple_Form in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript

I'm trying to add a bootstrap glyphicon to the right side of a form input using simple_form within rails.

This link shows the rendered result of what I am trying to get here (specifically, the glyphicon-remove which is to the right of the input): http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_horizontal_all&stacked=h

I know it has to have a span, and then the classes `glyphicon glyphicon-remove` within that span. I got the info from this site: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_glyphicons.asp

I'm trying to do this in coffeescript.  Coffee script code so far that doesn't work:

```
$('#serve_dev_sub_email').add("span").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove")
```

I also attempted this code, but it didn't work either:

```
$('#serv_dev_sub_email').add("span")
$('#serv_dev_sub_email').first().addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove")
```

Here is the `_form` partial:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@serv_dev_sub) do |f| %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <div>
        <%= f.input :email, placeholder: "myemail@domain.com" %>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill empty span in you `#input-element` and

```
$('#input-element span:first-child').addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove")
```

Comment: I tried that but it unfortunately did not work. I will add to original question other things I have tried.

Comment: Can you show the code of `#input-element` and it's inner content?

Comment: I can't see element with id `#input-element`

Comment: Please add commented space where you want to post your div

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are asking.  What I need to do is add a span to the element `#serv-dev-sub-email` so that I can add the glyphcon classes to that span. I can grab that element just fine.  It is adding the span to that element and then adding classes to that span.  That is where the trouble is.

Comment: Updated original question with link to desired output. Hopefully it makes my question more clear.

Answer (score -1):

here's what i did:

```
<div class="form-inputs">
  <%= f.input :email, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => 'myemail@domain.com' %>
  <%=link_to '',root_path,:class => 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove clear-email',:onclick => "$('.search-box').val('');"%>
</div>
```